Wpf Dragging a rectangle on a canvas causes it to flash/blink
I am trying to drag a rectangle on an empty canvas. However, when i drag it, it flashes/blinks constantly.
I put a debug and the x and y coordinates jump between where my mouse cursor currently is and several drags? behind? if that makes sense?
Example:

Update X: 638, Update Y: 382.66666666666663


Update X: 319.33333333333337, Update Y: 302.66666666666663


Update X: 638, Update Y: 382.66666666666663


Update X: 319.33333333333337, Update Y: 302.66666666666663

The issue now is in this area i think:
Canvas.Left="{Binding SelectionRectangle.X}"
Canvas.Top="{Binding SelectionRectangle.Y}"

If i set it to static numbers, the blinking stops but i cannot create a rectangle from any starting point.
Here is my View:
<Window x:Class="PdfPageTagger.Views.CanvasWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PdfPageTagger.Views" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PdfPageTagger.ViewModels"
        Title="Canvas Viewer" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,0,10,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Canvas x:Name="viewCanvas"  Background="Black"
                                    MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                    MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
                                    MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"
                       Visibility="{Binding IsDrawing, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                       Canvas.Left="{Binding SelectionRectangle.X}"
                       Canvas.Top="{Binding SelectionRectangle.Y}"
                       Width="{Binding SelectionRectangle.Width}"
                       Height="{Binding SelectionRectangle.Height}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

Here is the xaml.cs behind my view:
public partial class CanvasWindow : Window
{
    public CanvasWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new CanvasWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
        vm.OnRequestClose += (s, e) => this.Close();
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the ViewModel instance from the DataContext
        if (DataContext is CanvasWindowViewModel viewModel)
        {
            await viewModel.WindowLoaded();
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = DataContext as CanvasWindowViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.StartDrawingCommand.Execute(e);
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = DataContext as CanvasWindowViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.UpdateDrawingCommand.Execute(e);
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = DataContext as CanvasWindowViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.EndDrawingCommand.Execute(e);
        }
    }
}

Here is my ViewModel:
public class CanvasWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand StartDrawingCommand { get; }
        public ICommand UpdateDrawingCommand { get; }
        public ICommand EndDrawingCommand { get; }

        public CanvasWindowViewModel()
        {

            StartDrawingCommand = new DelegateCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(StartDrawing);
            UpdateDrawingCommand = new DelegateCommand<MouseEventArgs>(UpdateDrawing);
            EndDrawingCommand = new DelegateCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(EndDrawing);
        }


        private Rect _selectionRectangle;
        public Rect SelectionRectangle
        {
            get => _selectionRectangle;
            set
            {
                _selectionRectangle = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectionRectangle));
            }
        }

        private bool _isDrawing;
        public bool IsDrawing
        {
            get => _isDrawing;
            set
            {
                _isDrawing = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsDrawing));
            }
        }

        private Point _startPoint;
        private void StartDrawing(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                _startPoint = e.GetPosition(e.Source as IInputElement);
                SelectionRectangle = new Rect(_startPoint, new Size(0, 0));
                IsDrawing = true;
                Debug.WriteLine($"Start X: {_startPoint.X}, Start Y: {_startPoint.Y}");
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDrawing(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsDrawing)
            {
                var currentPoint = e.GetPosition(e.Source as IInputElement);
                var x = Math.Min(currentPoint.X, _startPoint.X);
                var y = Math.Min(currentPoint.Y, _startPoint.Y);
                var width = Math.Abs(currentPoint.X - _startPoint.X);
                var height = Math.Abs(currentPoint.Y - _startPoint.Y);
                SelectionRectangle = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Update X: {currentPoint.X}, Update Y: {currentPoint.Y}");
            }
        }

        private void EndDrawing(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            {
                IsDrawing = false;
                Debug.WriteLine("Drawing Ended");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Pages { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

        public event EventHandler OnRequestClose;

        public async Task WindowLoaded()
        {

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


.Width  and .Height are generally useless when it comes to binding sources; it's .ActualWidth and .ActualHeight one wants. I generally "capture" the mouse on mouse down if I intend to move something. And I have found no need for "proxies" when moving; which just adds another layer of indirection, latency and overhead.

Dragging an element in the view is the responsibility of view and should be handled in the code behind of the view rather than view model. It can also avoid the intervals of binding.

Hi @GerrySchmitz, sorry so  what you mean is that MouseMove is not needed here and I  should only track it base on MouseLeftButtonDown?

@emoacht, thanks for replying. ill try to move the code into my view and see if it helps. However, is this caused by the code being in the viewmodel rather than the view?

Hi all, thank you for the help. I managed to solve it by moving the code away from the ViewModel into the View.
